# Problema en log Postgres, Autentificacion SSL

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, pyqt, ssl, openssl

Desde que he formateado y puesto ubuntu 20.04 (venia de 16.04 y todo ok), cada vez que me conecto a alguna BD a traves de pgadmin o del ERP basado en QT al servidor Postgres Remoto, en el log del servidor me pinta el siguiente error:

```
[desconocido]@[desconocido] FATAL:  el protocolo 1234.5680 no está soportado: servidor soporta 1.0 hasta 3.0 

Si que conecta y funciona, pero pinta esa linea en el log cada vez que realizo una conexión.
```

He podido averiguar que el error es por el protocolo SSL o el SMB, ya que si lanzo el ticket (sudo kinit Administrador@dominio) el error desaparece hasta el siguiente reinicio.

Si me conecto a través de terminar postgress con psql -h server -U postgres -d "dbname=prueba **gssencmode=disable**" Tampoco da el error.

El problema es que el servidor si que tiene habilitado el ssl, y no quiero deshabilitarselo. En mis BD locales no hay ningún problema, es cuando establezco la conexión a cualquier BD del servidor remoto.

Pero como comento, no quiero tocar la configuración del servidor remoto. Si desde mi maquina local hago un kinit, y se genera el ticket hasta el siguiente reinicio no falla y no sale esa linea en el log de postgres.. la cosa seria hacer que el kinit ese fuera permanente o ver que puedo tocar en mi maquina para que no salte el error por el SSL, y así no tocar el servidor remoto.

Tiene que se algo de **sslmode disable o ssencmode disable** o del Kerberos, pero me pierdo y no se que mas probar.

A ver si me podéis iluminar. Mil gracias

Comment: Revisa el archivo de configuración de Postgres que se llama `postgresql.conf`, para más detalles consulta la [documentación](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/runtime-config-file-locations.html).

Comment: Eso he hecho pero me quedo igual.. gracias por tu comentario

Comment: Pulsa en [edit]  y muéstranos qué tienes en el archivo de configuración.

Comment: O algo de Kerberos... la verdad que llevo unos dias y no doy con la tecla..

Comment: He actualizado el post principal, con mejor explicación.

Comment: Mira si lo explicado en [este post](https://www.endpoint.com/blog/2015/05/28/postgres-unsupported-frontend-protocol) puede ayudarte. Hay también errores similares que han sido [reportados como bugs](https://bugs.gentoo.org/703242), no sé si sea tu caso, si la versión de postgresql en el servidor está actualizada, etc.

Comment: Si hago un sudo kdestroy tampoco sale el error en el log... que raro... si genero tiket, no falla, ni borro con kdestriy, no falla. sin hacer nada... error en el log    :(